# Laravel Sanctum /login not found

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, fortify, laravel-nova, laravel-sanctum

SPA : app.sp-ed.test

- vue 3/ vuex 4/ axios / typscript

Laravel : sp-ed.test   `//api for api access, /nova for nova access, web routes for public access`

- laravel 8 / sanctum / nova / fortify

error on posting to /login:
[image]

config/fortify.php

```
    <?php

use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Laravel\Fortify\Features;

return [

    'guard' => 'web',

    'passwords' => 'users',

    'username' => 'email',

    'email' => 'email',

    'home' => env('SPA_URL') . '/dashboard',

    'prefix' => '',

    'domain' => 'sp-ed.test',

    'middleware' => ['web'],

    'limiters' => [
        'login' => 'login',
        'two-factor' => 'two-factor',
    ],

    'views' => false,

    'features' => [
        Features::registration(),
        Features::resetPasswords(),
        Features::emailVerification(),
        Features::updateProfileInformation(),
        Features::updatePasswords(),
        /* Features::twoFactorAuthentication([
            'confirmPassword' => true,
        ]), */
    ],

];
```

config/sanctum.php

```
<?php

return [

    'stateful' => explode(',', env(
        'SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1'
    )),

    'expiration' => null,

    'middleware' => [
        'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    ],

];
```

After hours of trying to settle the csfr token issue, vue/axios posts to the api can't find the /login route. To me the interesting point in this error is the middleware "ServeNova" being called.  I have printed out the routes and the login route looks correct [image included]. This seems like a complex implementation and I'm sure I missed something small. Does anyone have an idea of what might be wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand why, but in my case i was facing the same issue and running `php artisan migrate:fresh` fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

This happens dues to after making register api call you try to login! however, you are already logged in!

When you make register it automatically login, therefore, if you want to use login API call, you have to logout first after that login again.

OR you can prevent login request if user already logged in.